# AIRFLOW task fails with SIGTERM error while transferring large volume files to cloud object storage

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are using AIRFLOW tasks to push file to S3 Object storage, which runs perfectly fine excepts very high volume files(eg: 5GB). For very high volume files the task is failing with below Error.

```
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,416] {taskinstance.py:605} DEBUG - Refreshed TaskInstance <TaskInstance: DAG1.task1 2021-07-28T12:48:29+00:00 [None]>
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,418] {local_task_job.py:188} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to None. Terminating instance.
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,457] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 29564
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,457] {taskinstance.py:1239} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,457] {bash.py:185} INFO - Sending SIGTERM signal to bash process group
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,458] {taskinstance.py:570} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: DAG1.task1 2021-07-28T12:48:29+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,484] {taskinstance.py:605} DEBUG - Refreshed TaskInstance <TaskInstance: DAG1.task1 2021-07-28T12:48:29+00:00 [None]>
[2021-07-29 11:24:32,486] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/amex/app/airflow/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1112, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/amex/app/airflow/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/amex/app/airflow/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/amex/app/airflow/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 171, in execute
    for raw_line in iter(self.sub_process.stdout.readline, b''):
  File "/amex/app/airflow/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1241, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
```

We are using boto3 to push to S3 object storage, but not able to figure out what is causing the issue. We have changed killed_task_cleanup_time = 60 to killed_task_cleanup_time = 21600 in airflow.cfg, but still getting the same error.
We have postgresql as our airflow metadata database.

Comment: The implication from the log is that this has been running for 22.5 hours, since 12:48 yesterday.  That's way more than 21600 seconds.  A day is 86400 seconds.

Comment: How are pushing those files to S3? The error points to a resource constraint in the Airflow environment. Are you trying to pull in the data/file(s) into Airflow and then push to S3?

Comment: This is indicative of a resource contention on your airflow instance - either compute or memory. Have you tried implementing [multipart uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html)?

Comment: @JoshFell We have these files present in NAS path. Airflow triggers one job which internally calls a python program to transfer the files to S3 using boto3.

Comment: @VinayKulkarni We have tried multipart uploads with threads in python, but it almost taking same time to load and still we are getting the SIGTERM error.